# Eador: Doh-Gor's Medallion

Tags: eador

I have defeated Doh-Gor and obtained his Medallion - what can/should i do with it? are there other options than

- releasing the god of war
- throw it into the chaos

### Doh-Gor:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you can only either throw it into the chaos, take it to the masters to release the god trapped inside, or sell it to Beleth for an amount of energy. There are no other known uses for it that I could find on the forums or the wiki. [According to the wiki](https://eador-masters-of-the-broken-world.fandom.com/wiki/Doh-Gor%27s_Amulet):

> Once you have Doh-Gor's Amulet, you can either **throw it in after him**, or **take it to the other masters and ask about it.**
>
> - Asking **Oinor** about the amulet reveals that it has a powerful immortal trapped within it. He will teach you the spell to unbind it if asked. If you use the spell, it will decrease your relationship with Oinor.
> - If Oinor refuses to talk to you because you've been evil, you can talk to **Beleth** about it and get the spell from him instead if he still exists. Beleth will also offer to buy the amulet for various prices, up to 300 energy. He'll also ask for 100 energy to tell you the spell, but you can threaten to kill him and force him to tell it to you for free if you're strong enough.
>
> Once you have the spell, you can then choose to release whatever is within or destroy it. If released, a god of war and rage is released who claims to have been trapped in the gem by demons. If asked for a reward, he will laugh and say that not being destroyed by him is your reward. Replying that you would welcome the attack makes him deem you worthy of a reward. He informs you that he created the Orcs, and could form a permanent alliance with them for you if you so wish (note that this does NOT raise the normal limit of one alliance per shard, thus all other races are permanently disqualified from alliance!). He then leaves to bring war to the demons that imprisoned him.

Comment: Thanks - i didn´t know Beleth was interested in the amulett - since i already threw him down into the eternal chaos... great answer!!!